# Second record from xml in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

My xslt works only for the first record from the XMl but not for the other records.i am not sure how to get the other records populated through xslt .I am sure its something to do with Hotel order = but i am new to XMl stuff so please help.

Please help me

The code for xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DestinationResults size="1">
  <Destination name="Paris, FRA" order="1">
    <HotelAvailabilityListResults size="10">
      <Hotel order="1">
        <hotelId>188139</hotelId>
        <name>
          <![CDATA[ Hotel Magenta Paris ]]>
        </name>
        <address1>38 Boulevard De Magenta</address1>
        <address2/>
        <address3/>
        <city>Paris</city>
        <stateProvince/>
        <country>FR</country>
        <postalCode>75010</postalCode>
        <latitude>48.87203</latitude>
        <longitude>2.35995</longitude>
        <tripAdvisorRating>4.0</tripAdvisorRating>
        <fromDate>10/11/2013</fromDate>
        <toDate>10/12/2013</toDate>
        <shortDescription>
          <![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Property Location&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;With a stay at Hotel Magenta Paris in Paris (Gare du Nord - Gare de L&apos;Est), you&apos;ll be minutes from Porte Saint-Martin and close to Louvre Museum. This]]>
        </shortDescription>
        <thumbNailUrl>
http://origin-images.ian.com/hotels/1000000/890000/889000/888903/888903_22_t.jpg
        </thumbNailUrl>
        <propertyRating>3.0</propertyRating>
        <referenceProximityDistance>-1.0</referenceProximityDistance>
        <referenceProximityUnit/>
        <HotelProperty>
          <promoDescription>Stay 1 nights and save 10% off your stay!</promoDescription>
          <ValueAdds>
            <valueAdd id="2048">Free Wireless Internet</valueAdd>
          </ValueAdds>
          <PromoRateInfo>
            <displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
            <DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
              <displayNightlyRate>152.02</displayNightlyRate>
            </DisplayNightlyRates>
            <displayRoomRate>168.68</displayRoomRate>
            <chargeableRoomRateTotal>168.68</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
            <chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
            <taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
            <salesTax>0</salesTax>
            <hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
            <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
            <NativeNightlyRates size="1">
              <nativeNightlyRate>152.02</nativeNightlyRate>
            </NativeNightlyRates>
            <nativeRoomRate>168.68</nativeRoomRate>
            <rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
          </PromoRateInfo>
          <RateInfo>
            <displayCurrencyCode>USD</displayCurrencyCode>
            <DisplayNightlyRates size="1">
              <displayNightlyRate>168.91</displayNightlyRate>
            </DisplayNightlyRates>
            <displayRoomRate>185.57</displayRoomRate>
            <chargeableRoomRateTotal>185.57</chargeableRoomRateTotal>
            <chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>16.66</chargeableRoomRateTaxesAndFees>
            <taxesOnly>16.66</taxesOnly>
            <salesTax>0</salesTax>
            <hotelOccupancyTax>0</hotelOccupancyTax>
            <nativeCurrencyCode>USD</nativeCurrencyCode>
            <NativeNightlyRates size="1">
              <nativeNightlyRate>168.91</nativeNightlyRate>
            </NativeNightlyRates>
            <nativeRoomRate>185.57</nativeRoomRate>
            <rateFrequency>B</rateFrequency>
          </RateInfo>
        </HotelProperty>
        <hotelUrl>
http://booking.rated-hotels.co.uk/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=409870&hotelID=188139&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=9&arrivalDay=11&departureMonth=9&departureDay=12&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&mcicid=409870.HOTEL.XML.85419
        </hotelUrl>
      </Hotel>

    </HotelAvailabilityListResults>
  </Destination>
</DestinationResults>
```

and my Xslt is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

    <xsl:for-each select="DestinationResults">
    <xsl:for-each select="Destination">
    <xsl:for-each select="HotelAvailabilityListResults">
    <xsl:for-each select="Hotel">

      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
        - <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="shortDescription"/>.
        <span style="font-style:italic">
          <xsl:value-of select="address1"/> 
        </span>.</p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the xml sample has one hotel

Comment: and you have well-formedness errors (non-escaped ampersands in the hotelUrl). And I'm not sure about the CDATA blocks; why is some of the data in CDATA blocks and some not? It looks random.

Comment: changing the ampersands in the URL to `%26` would be a good place to start too.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the xml and xsl out oun an online tester at http://xslttest.appspot.com/  and for the most part seems ok, once you remove the first two lines of your xslt, and change the & signs in urls to %26 (for urls remember to url encode any special characters, for xml fields remember to xml encode)

a 2 entry xml file is [here](http://pastebin.com/z4sdMm4u)

and a modified xsl file is [here](http://pastebin.com/5iNzE0uT)

The xsl transformation returns both entries for me, but you will still need to correct some of the formattin on values to ensure it displays correctly.